# Can I pass several variables (set and maps) to finish method of batch

Tags: apex, batch, map, set, global-variables

I have a batch process which loops trough records to count different statuses per user. I store these in a map. When the Batch is done I want to update the results on an aggregated object.

How do I pass the set and maps to the finish method to update the values on the aggregated object or do I need to create a sub batch process for this.

I have the following. When I do a system debug in the finish method I do not get results

```
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Workethic__c> scope)
    { 
        if(scope.size() > 0)
        {
            for(Workethic__c workEts : scope){
                userIds.add(workEts.User__c);
                if(earlyCount.containsKey(workEts.User__c) && workEts.WorkethicStatus__c == 'Early'){
                    earlyCount.put(workEts.User__c,earlyCount.get(workEts.User__c)+1);
                }else if (workEts.WorkethicStatus__c == 'Early'){
                    earlyCount.put(workEts.User__c,1);   
                }
                if(lateCount.containsKey(workEts.User__c) && workEts.WorkethicStatus__c == 'Late'){
                    lateCount.put(workEts.User__c,lateCount.get(workEts.User__c)+1);
                }else if ( workEts.WorkethicStatus__c == 'Late'){
                    lateCount.put(workEts.User__c,1);
                }              
            }
        }
       
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
       System.debug('earlyCount Map : '+ earlyCount); 
        System.debug('userIds Finishmethod: '+ userIds); 
        List<AggregatedResult__c> aggResults = [select id, Early_TotalScore__c  from AggregatedResult__c where id IN :userIds]; 
.. Update List
    }
```

Comment: You can use Database.Stateful interface and create a instance variable to retain the map or list and use it in finish method.

Comment: @BalwinderKumar Thanks!, so simple. Can you add this as an answer other wise I will delete the question

Comment: note that Database.Stateful consumes heap so if your maps are huge (12MB) , you may have an issue - normally this is not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please implement Database.Stateful interface and create instance variable in the class to hold the map or list. Same can be used in finish method.

[Salesforce Developer Guide around Database.Stateful interface usage.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#:%7E:text=When%20using%20Database.,records%20as%20they%27re%20processed.)